Trying to cut a row from one sheet to another based on cell content in one row
Here is the code I have it is only copying one row over to sheet 2 and I have not been able to figure out why.  I just want to look through column ED and find some text, cut the row and put it in sheet 2.  But it cuts the rows but only pastes one row in sheet 2.
Dim fCell As Range
Dim wsSearch As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet


Set wsSearch = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")



With wsSearch.Range("ED:ED")

Set fCell = .Find(what:="Balance Forward from EPIC", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)

Do Until fCell Is Nothing
    fCell.EntireRow.Cut Destination:=wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    fCell.EntireRow.Delete

        Set fCell = .Find(what:="Balance Forward from EPIC", LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False)
    Loop
End With


Can you include some sample example of the sheet you're pulling from and the one you're copying too? Try a Mark down table. Also do you work for Epic and can I get an upgraded skin in Fortnite?

No I do not work for Epic, sorry.  This is getting frustrating it is only pulling one row no matter what I do.  I cannot figure out why the code is not looping and moving to next caught text in the column to move to sheet2

Even if it is not my code, there has got to be a way to look through a column and if certain text is found, cut the row and put it into a different sheet.

Is column A populated? You might overwrite the pasted row otherwise. Might need wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "ED") instead of wsDest.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A"). Technically, that should be wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "ED")

thanks guys I found it.  For some reason I had it looking in column A to count up and there was nothing in it after the initial one.  Just air headed it.  Thanks again

After your initial FIND you should use FINDNEXT to look for further instances.  Range.Find method has a good example.

Move Matching Rows
Before

After


Your code will not work correctly even after it is amended in the way you suggested in your most recent comment.
Try the following instead. It is similar to what Darren Bartrup-Cook suggested in your comments.
Using AdvancedFilter or AutoFilter would be more efficient.

Sub MoveMatchingRows()
    
    ' Workbook
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Source (Search)
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Columns("ED")
    Dim slcell As Range: Set slcell = srg.Cells(srg.Cells.Count)
    
    ' Destination
    
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Sheets("Sheet2")
    ' The destination sheet has always the 'ED' column populated!
    ' When pasting entire rows, the destination column must be column 'A'!
    Dim dcell As Range: Set dcell = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, "ED").End(xlUp) _
        .Offset(1).EntireRow.Columns("A")
    
    ' First Found Cell

    ' The last cell ('slcell') is used as the argument of the 'After' parameter
    ' combined with the omitted default argument 'xlNext'
    ' of the 'SearchDirection' parameter
    ' i.e. the search will start after the given (last) cell ('ED1048576')
    ' i.e. with the next (first) cell ('ED1').
    ' The 'xlFormulas' argument of the 'LookIn' parameter will ensure
    ' that a cell is found even if it (its row or column) is hidden.
    ' The 'Find' method will fail if the worksheet is filtered!
    Dim scell As Range:
    Set scell = srg.Find(What:="Balance Forward from EPIC", _
        After:=slcell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        
    ' Check if there is no matching cell.
    If scell Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No cell found!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Status:
    ' At this point the first cell was found
    ' i.e. at least one row will be moved.
    
    ' Unioned Range
    
    ' The address of the first found cell will determine when to exit the loop.
    Dim FirstAddress As String: FirstAddress = scell.Address
    
    ' Add the first cell to the unioned range.
    Dim surg As Range: Set surg = scell
    
    Do
        ' Combine each found cell into a unioned range.
        ' No harm done when adding the first cell a second time.
        Set surg = Union(surg, scell)
        ' Use the 'FindNext' method to find the next cell.
        ' It uses the same arguments used with the (initial) 'Find' method
        ' except for the 'After' parameter.
        Set scell = srg.FindNext(After:=scell)
    Loop Until scell.Address = FirstAddress
        
    ' Move Rows.
        
    ' You cannot cut a non-contiguous range. Therefore copy and delete.
    With surg.EntireRow
        .Copy Destination:=dcell
        .Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Matching rows moved.", vbInformation
        
End Sub

